# Matlab computing wrong values

Tags: matlab, security, debugging, image-processing, steganography

I am using MATLAB 2013a to implement the algorithm of this paper [An improved method for high hiding capacity based on LSB and PVD](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/B9780128194386000116)

Figure 3.1 in the paper describes the embedding procedure, when reaching the 5th step of the right branch, MATLAB computes wrong values for the variables **v1** and **v2**. Here is my code:

```
counter =1;
for i=1:size(stego,1)
    for j=1:3:size(stego,2)
        %% Step 1: Let the three pixels of a block be Pi, Pi+1, and Pi+2.
        p0 = stego(i,j);
        p1 = stego(i,j+1);
        p2 = stego(i,j+2);
        %% Step 2: Suppose Pi <= Pi+1 and Pi <= Pi+2.
        if (p0 <= p1 && p0 <=p2)
          % some code is here.....
        else
          % Otherwise, the reference pixel is Pi+1, and apply the steps 8 to 12
            % to produce the stego-pixels.
            bits = sm(1, counter:counter+k-1); %sm is a binary string 0011101101011.....
            counter = counter+k;
            g1 = dec2bin(p1,8);
            k_old = bin2dec(g1(1,end-k+1:end));
            g1(1,end-k+1:end) = bits;
            k_new = bin2dec(bits);
            g1 = bin2dec(g1);

        % Compute the difference value kdif = kold ?knew.
        k_diff = k_old - k_new;
        
        % Now, compute P'i+1 using Eq. (3.22).
        if (k_diff > 2^(k-1) && (g1+2^k>=0 && g1+2^k<=255))
            p_1 = g1 + 2^k;
        elseif (k_diff < -2^(k-1) && (g1 - 2^k >=0 && g1 - 2^k <= 255))
            p_1 = g1 - 2^k;
        else
            p_1 = g1;
        end

        v11 = abs(p0 - p_1); %ERROR HAPPENS HERE
        v22 = abs(p2 - p_1); %ERROR HAPPENS HERE

        % REST OF THE CODE ....
```

(I've removed the code of the left branch as it has no problems)

While debugging my code, matlab shows me correctly the values of **p0** which is equal to 64 and **p_1** which is equal to 66, so equation *v11 = abs(p0 - p_1);* must yield 2. But it gives **v11 = 0**.

[Here is a screenshot of the values of the variables **p0**, **p_1**, and the result of **v11** after executing the line while debugging.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uBlxO.png)

So, is that a Matlab bug? Or there is a problem with my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your debugging, notice that `p0` is of type `uint8` with value 64, that is, an unsigned 8-bit integer, while `p_1` is a `double`. When subtracting a double from a `uint8`, the result will be a `uint8`, which can't represent negative values. Matlab unsigned integers saturate so the result will be zero.

I'd recommend changing the type of `p0` to a signed integer type (maybe just `int8` is sufficient).

Comment: Or better, just write `abs(double(p0) - p_1)`.

Comment: Yeah, it depends on the context. I think probably `p_1` should be created as an integer initially since the code appears to be about images.